# More of this type $T_n^2+T_{n+1}^2+T_{n+2}^2=X^2?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Given triangular numbers,

$$T_n:= {n(n+1)\over 2} = 1,3,6,10,15,...$$

Let $T_n, T_{n+1}$ and $T_{n+2}$ be three consecutive triangular numbers.

**My question is: Are there more of $T_n^2+T_{n+1}^2+T_{n+2}^2$ that only yield a square number?** Or this is $$T_3^2+T_4^2+T_5^2=6^2+10^2+15^2=19^2$$ the only one? I can't seem to find anymore.

Comment: There are no more solutions up to $n$ 100 million.

Comment: In fact, there are no more solutions for $X$ below $10^{10000}$. If anyone would like to see the code used to check this, feel free to drop me a message.

Comment: @B.Mehta. I would like to see the code. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I've posted an explanation and some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked this for all $X$ up to $10^{10^5}$, here's how.
We are searching for integer solutions to $T_{n-1}^2 + T_n^2 + T_{n+1}^2 = X^2$ (note I've reparametrised, compared to the OP), which expands to
$$3 n^4 + 6 n^3 + 15 n^2 + 12 n + 4 =4X^2. $$ 
Curiously enough, this is an invertible expression, and [we can instead say](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%203%20n%5E4%20%2B%206%20n%5E3%20%2B%2015%20n%5E2%20%2B%2012%20n%20%2B%204%20%3D4X%5E2%20for%20n)
$$n = \frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{24 \sqrt{3X^2 + 6} - 63}- 3\right)$$
assuming $n>0$.

For $n$ to be an integer, $\sqrt{24 \sqrt{3X^2 + 6} - 63}$ must be an integer, so $24 \sqrt{3X^2 + 6} - 63$ must be a square. Furthermore, it must be an integer, hence $ \sqrt{3X^2 + 6}$ must be an integer. (Note that $3X^2 + 6$ is an integer, so $ \sqrt{3X^2 + 6}$ is either an integer or irrational - being $\frac{1}{24}$ of an integer cannot work.) So, it suffices to search for integer solutions $(X,Y)$ to the equation $Y^2 - 3X^2 = 6$ such that $24Y-63$ is a square.

But, these are easy to generate, with some knowledge of Pell equations. I'll switch to talking about $x^2 - 3y^2 = 6$ for now, for consistency with literature.  First observe that the equation $a^2 - 3b^2 = 1$ has a solution given by $(a,b) = (2, 1)$, and that this is the positive non-trivial solution with smallest $b$. By Theorem 5.3 (and Example 5.6) in [Keith Conrad's first blurb on Pell equations](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn1.pdf), all solutions to this equation are generated by this one.  Consulting [Keith Conrad's second blurb on Pell equations](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf), we can see that every other solution is a Pell multiple of this one.  Considering the original equation $x^2 - 3y^2 = 6$ now, Theorem 3.3 in the second blurb tells us that every solution of this is given by a Pell multiple of a solution $(x_1, y_1)$ where $|x_1| \leq 22$ and $|y_1| \leq 7$. A quick computer check gives only $(3, 1)$ and $(9, 5)$ as the positive solutions here, and $(9, 5)$ is a Pell multiple of $(3, 1)$.

Hence, all solutions of $x^2 - 3y^2 = 6$ are Pell multiples of $(3, 1)$, where the next Pell multiple of pair $(x, y)$ is given by $(2x + 3y, x + 2y)$, so we can easily generate all the positive integer solutions in Haskell! (using the `arithmoi` library)

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Squares

recurse :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer)
recurse (a, b) = (2*a + 3*b, a + 2*b)

vals :: [(Integer, Integer)]
vals = iterate recurse (3, 1)

works :: (Integer, Integer) -> Bool
works (n, _) = isSquare' (24 * n - 63)

solutions :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
solutions limit = filter works bounded
    where bounded = takeWhile (\(y, x) -> x < limit) vals
```

`vals` is a list of the solutions to the Pell equation, generated using the recurrence explained above. A pair $(Y, X) = (x, y)$ `works` if $24Y - 63$ is a square, checked using the arithmoi package for number theory.  Finally, `solutions limit` checks every possible $(Y, X)$ that satisfies `X < limit` to see if it `works` or not.

`solutions (10^(10^5))` gives `[(3, 1), (33, 19)]` and the pair $(3, 1)$ corresponds to the trivial solution $T_{-1}^2 + T_0^2 + T_1^2 = 1$, while $(33, 19)$ corresponds to the solution in the OP. In particular, $24 \times 33 - 63 = 729$, so $n=4$, and $T_3^2 + T_4^2 + T_5^2 = 19$.

My computer checks this in under two minutes, but fails for $10^{10^6}$, seemingly due to memory errors.  Hopefully someone can grow this into a full proof using cleverer ideas about Pell equations, or check larger values.

EDIT: Now checked up to $10^{2\times {10^5}}$.

Comment: This is really a nice answer ! Thanks for posting it. Cheers $+ \to +1$ indeed.